# Load data dynamically in a form with Django

Tags: python, ajax, django, forms

is it possible to build a Django form with a select containing some data and, when the user select an option on that select, add another select with related data (i.e. sub-categories)?

For example, I have a Django model like

```
class ShoppingList (models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name='item', verbose_name=_('item'))
    quantity = models.SmallIntegerField(_('quantity'), default=1)
```

where *item* is a ForeignKey related to another model like

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(_('description'), max_length=500, default="")
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='category', verbose_name=_('category'))
```

and *category* is another model similar to *item* but without the third field.

What I need is a form that shows to the user a list (select) of categories. When the user select a category, a new select should appear containing the items of that category. The other fields of the model ShoppingList should also appear.

I guess that I need Ajax for that but I don't know how to integrate it with Django forms.

Comment: Try messing around with [django form wizard](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) and ajax. You could create your forms and then based on selection pull in required form from the form wizard using ajax

Comment: Yes but every form needs to have a copy of the _request_ object to get the id of the logged user, so how can I do this with WizardForm?

Comment: You can do this by adding the user object to the form in the view. Take a look at [WizardView.get_form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views.WizardView.get_form)